# jquery validation : save conflict error should popup when user tries to add similar data

Tags: infopath, jquery

When a user tries to add data for two fields which were already selected in the previous new item, it should not allow the user to save, validation error should be thrown..

Sharepoint should check through the list and found for the possible combination. for example: product and price are two fields. User selected product value as "bat" and price as "100" and saved it. Then in a new form when user try to add same values for two fields it should not be aloowed to save. Can i solve using jquery

Actually it is a infopath form. Since these two fields were multiselection listbox and merge data during publishing. I am not able to retrieve data to a textbox to concat two field data and set it as unique column. unfortunately i cant do this due to this multiselectionlistbox.

Comment: server coding is not allowed for me....help me by using script

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I solved it..

I created a master list for the multichoice field and a unique textbox field with values related to ID of some pattern  (eg: for product - PD1) in the Sharepoint List
In Infopath form I provided  a textbox for multichoice fields, with values,

eval(eval(ubcg[Title = field2][. != ""], 'concat(., "; ")'), ".."),

where i added the textbox pattern ID for the selected choices..that will be displayed in the infopath textbox field in ascending order.

Now create a textbox in site column with unique enforce values and while publishing map it to the infopath textbox field, which has the selected choices unique pattern values.

Create a new form and check for duplicate values...

It sounds good as it is working fine..